# JS canvas animations not finding correct mouse positions with offset

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I have created a canvas with the particle animations.
The animations work fine. However the do go over the y axis min and max a little bit.

The particles should move out of the way of the mouse.
This works fine in the top left hand corner where the coords are 0,0
However as i move out towards the bottom right, the area of the canvas that believes it has the mouse over becomes further away from the actual mouse position.
It lags by about 250px.

Because of this when i try to apply the offset to the mouse it will make one corner of the canvas better and the other corner worse.

I have added some spots in exact positions and a center line just to check im getting at least somethings correct. and these all appear in the correct position. Even after a screen resize.

The fact that my animations go off the y axis makes me think the canvas is stretching somehow and thats moving the mouse. However its weird that point 0,0 doesnt have this issues and it get worse the further you go.

I have made a code pen link https://codepen.io/tomsilhouette/pen/poqaJRB
It seems to be better on code pen, making me think it has alot to do with the container sizes.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvasInt');
console.log('canvas', canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log('ctx', ctx);

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let particlesArray;

let mouse = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    radius: (canvas.height / 150) * (canvas.width / 150),
};

let redCircleSize = 15; // Adjust the size of the red circle as needed

function drawRedCircle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(1, 1, redCircleSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.arc(canvas.width, canvas.height, redCircleSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, redCircleSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; // Set the fill color to red
    ctx.fill();
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    // Get the position of the canvas element
    var canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log("canvasRect", canvasRect)
    console.log("MOVEEEEeee", e)
    // Calculate the mouse coordinates relative to the canvas
    var mouseX = e.clientX - canvasRect.left;
    var mouseY = e.clientY - canvasRect.top;

    // Update the mouse object with the relative coordinates
    mouse.x = mouseX;
    mouse.y = mouseY;

    console.log("CANVASSSS", canvas.width, canvas.height);
    console.log("Mouse coordinates relative to canvas:", mouseX, mouseY);
});

class Particle {
    constructor(x, y, directionX, directionY, size, colour) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.directionX = directionX;
        this.directionY = directionY;
        this.size = size;
        this.colour = colour;
    }

    // draw each particle
    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = `#8C5523`;
        ctx.fill();
    }

    // check particle position
    update() {
        // check is particle is still in canvas
        if (this.x > canvas.width || this.x < 0) {
            this.directionX = -this.directionX;
        }
        if (this.y > canvas.height || this.y < 0) {
            this.directionY = -this.directionX;
        }

        // check for collision
        let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
        let dy = mouse.y - this.y;

        let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        if (distance < mouse.radius + this.size) {
            if (mouse.x < this.x && this.x < canvas.width - this.size * 10) {
                this.x += 10;
            }
            if (mouse.x > this.x && this.x > this.size * 10) {
                this.x -= 10;
            }
            if (mouse.y < this.y && this.y < canvas.height - this.size * 10) {
                this.y += 10;
            }
            if (mouse.y > this.y && this.y > this.size * 10) {
                this.y -= 10;
            }
        }
        // move
        this.x += this.directionX;
        this.y += this.directionY;

        // draw
        this.draw();
    }
}

// create particle array
function init() {
    particlesArray = [];
    let numberOfParticles = (canvas.height * canvas.width) / 8000;

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfParticles * 2; i++) {
        let size = Math.random() * 5 + 1;
        let x = Math.random() * (innerWidth - size * 2 - size * 2) + size * 2;
        let y = Math.random() * (innerHeight - size * 2 - size * 2) + size * 2;
        let directionX = Math.random() * 5 - 2.5;
        let directionY = Math.random() * 5 - 2.5;
        let colour = '#8C5523';

        particlesArray.push(
            new Particle(x, y, directionX, directionY, size, colour)
        );
    }
}

// check if particles are close enough to draw a line between
function connect() {
    let opacityValue = 1;
    for (let a = 0; a < particlesArray.length; a++) {
        for (let b = 0; b < particlesArray.length; b++) {
            let distance = ((particlesArray[a].x - particlesArray[b].x) * (particlesArray[a].x - particlesArray[b].x)) + ((particlesArray[a].y - particlesArray[b].y) * (particlesArray[a].y - particlesArray[b].y));

            if (distance < (canvas.width / 7) * (canvas.height / 7)) {
                opacityValue = 1 - (distance / 20000)
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(140,85,31,' + opacityValue + ')';
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(particlesArray[a].x, particlesArray[a].y);
                ctx.lineTo(particlesArray[b].x, particlesArray[b].y);
                ctx.stroke()
            }
        }
    }
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight);

    for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
        particlesArray[i].update();
    }

    connect()
    drawCenterLine();
    drawRedCircle()
}

// resize screen
window.addEventListener('resize',
    function () {
        console.log("PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP", innerHeight)
        canvas.width = innerWidth;
        canvas.height = innerHeight;
        mouse.radius = ((canvas.height / 80) * (canvas.height / 80))
        init()
    }
)

// mouse out event
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout',
    function () {
        console.log("MOUSE OUT")

        mouse.x = undefined;
        mouse.y = undefined;
    }
)


function drawCenterLine() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black'; // Set the line color to black
    ctx.lineWidth = 2; // Set the line width (adjust as needed)
    ctx.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, 0); // Start at the center top of the canvas
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height); // Draw down to the center bottom
    ctx.stroke(); // Draw the line
}

export function initializeCanvas() {
    init();
    drawCenterLine();
    animate();
}

initializeCanvas()

    #canvasInt {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: radial-gradient(#ffcfac, #ff9b40 );
    }

<div class="h-screen relative">
    <div class="flex bg-gray-100 h-full">
        <div class="hidden md:grid md:grid-rows-nav bg-slate-600 h-full min-w-[250px] border-r-2 border-black border-solid h-full">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>

        <main class="w-full grid grid-rows-canvas">
            <div>
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </div>

            <section>
                <button class="px-2 py-1 bg-main-colour hover:brightness-90 active:scale-95" @onclick="LogUserIn">Log In</button>
            </section>

            <section class="grid relative w-full h-full p-4">
                <canvas id="canvasInt">
                </canvas>
            </section>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Various offsets and resetting the mouse position